# Understanding how types could be pointer interconvertible for reinterpret_cast to be valid

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to understand the usage of `reinterpret_cast` in template functions where a generic type could be passed in, and inside the function, you want to cast the object to a said struct without eliciting UB.

```c
struct PktStruct
{
   uint8_t _value = 1;
   PktStruct (uint8_t value) : _value(value) {};
   virtual ~PktStruct() = default;
};

template <typename T>
void bar(T *data)
{
    PktStruct *pkt = reinterpret_cast<PktStruct*>(new T(*data));
}
```

From what I have read, `reinterpret_cast` is well-defined as long as object types are interconvertible.

According to [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#pointer-interconvertible):

> one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object

What does the last line imply particularly "any base class subobject of that object"? I am trying to relate this to my example to see what kind of types could be passed into `bar` so `reinterpret_cast` remains well-defined.

Also perhaps it would be a good idea to invoke `reinterpret_cast` iff `std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of_v<Base, Derived>` == true to avoid the chances of invoking UB?

Comment: Since your class has "non-static data members", none of that applies. The only valid template parameter is `PktStruct`.

Comment: none of what applies?

Comment: What that paragraph says, to this template.

Comment: non static data member is a sign of a standard layout which is among the requirements for pointer types being interconvertible.

Comment: Well, yes, as in "the object has no non-static data members", then the pointer types are interconvertible, in the manner described. Since `PktStruct` has "non-static data members", then this requirement is not met.

Comment: I'm confused. `PkgStruct` certainly has a non-static member variable which is the among the requirements of a pointer being interconvertible

Comment: The way I read this is that only if there are ***no*** non-static data member, they are interconvertible. Your quoted paragraph reads: "if the object has no non-static data members", I definitely see the word "no" in there.

Comment: You are trying to pun a type, and that's never gonna work. Use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: "pun a type". mind elaborating?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you might wanna read the phrase before `or` in the quote

Comment: Note that those rules are for `static_cast`.  The rules for `reinterpret_cast` are stricter than just being pointer-interconvertible.

Comment: @MilesBudnek "reinterpret_cast<T&>(u) always has well-defined result if std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of_v<T, U>  is true."

Comment: `PktStruct` is definitely *not* standard-layout. It has a *virtual function* (destructor, albeit defaulted). In no way can it be treated like a C struct, neither with casting pointers nor with `memcpy`.

Comment: For standard layout classes, all non-static data members should be declared in the same class. Thus each base class is either empty or contains all of the non-static data members. PktStruct isn't standard layout though.

Comment: thanks. since `PktStruct` is a non-standard layout, `reinterpret_cast` would render UB.
To your comment @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: so there two cases: either base class is empty OR derived class is empty and base class contains ALL the non-static data members? is that it?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it make sense to have a condition (`std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of_v<Base, Derived>`) prior to running reinterpret_cast to ensure that's no chances of UB?